# How to self joining table from following scenario?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider I have a table named table1 which contains following data:

```
id, value
1, a
1, b
1, c
1, d
2, a
2, b
2, c
3, b
3, c
4, a
4, b
4, c
4, d
```

I wanted to select all ids that have a value = d. How could I achieve this?

Which means I need to get the result of ( **1 and 4** ) , since  id 2 and 3 do not contain d.

the actual table contains more than 10,000,000 rows, so the query should not be too slow.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: This is a *completely different question* with that edit. You have just invalidated everyone's answer below, so I am rolling your edit back. Please ask a new question with your new information instead.

Comment: In this case it turns out to be a stupid question, maybe you can just delete it away, not need to draw anyone else'a attention, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The converse problem of how to list all the IDs that do not have an entry 'd' (answer 2 and 3) is considerably harder to answer than this one.  You could rescue the question and still get both answers by putting a "_Edit:_ Also, how can I find the ids that do _not_ have a value of 'd' associated with them?"  That leaves the original answers correct (though unavoidably incomplete w.r.t the revised question).  As the asker of a question, you have a duty of courtesy to those who have tried to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a join at all:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable
WHERE value = 'd'
```

Comment: Impressed by your quick response, but wait, I will update to the real situation.

Comment: Sorry bro, my fault to mis-lead you . ;-(

Comment: I think this query is really OK. To speed up, you can create INDEX property for value column.

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty straight forward. (*There is no need for join*)

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  value = 'd'
```

Comment: your question was rolled back, here's the answer for that `SELECT *
    FROM   TableName
    WHERE  value <> 'd'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select id
from Table1
where value= 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this query it will help you

```
select * from table1 t, table1 t1 
where t.value = t1.value and t1.value='d'
```